# Connect a Container to an external computer in the network

Tags: docker, networking

As the title says. I have an Music Player and a Music Library Manager in my *expandable* Docker Host, but for storage constraints, the database and files reside outside the host, inside another machine (NAS) of the same network.

[image]

I've setup static IP for those for obvious reasons, but while the container has access to the router with DHCP for Internerds (`172.16.0.1`), and a ping to there works, a ping to `172.16.1.1` doesn't works (Host) and neither `172.16.1.2` (NAS). So I can't reach the database nor the files.

What should I do to successfully connect the container to the external machine? The NAS is reachable and all systems are OK.

Comment: How did you startup your containers? Did you expose and publish the ports with `-p 3306:3306`? Did you check your firewall settings?

Comment: MySQL connectivity is OK. NAS connectivity is all OK. I don't know what do you mean with "firewall settings", what should I look for?

Comment: For example, if you run docker containers on a linux computer where firewalld or apparmor is activated, this could interefere with the docker network not allowing you to connect to the docker services. For example on ubuntu I check it with `sudo service firewalld status`

Comment: Also have a look at `docker ps` and see if the ports are correctly exposed and published

Comment: `netstat -tulpen` on your endpoint server to look if your docker service is actually mapping the ports to the host machine and not to any other docker-network, OR maybe any other service is already using the ports so docker cannot use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should set the network mode to `host` for your containers.
to change network mode for containers add `--network host` for running the container!

Comment: That did it. I'll have to heck my networking though, because I did the same on other machine without using the host network and I could reach the LAN and WAN outside the container.